# org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found when importing Gears API in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, xerces

I've created a [GWT](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/) project using Eclipse which was working perfectly (I was able to run it in both Hosted Mode and on Google App Engine) until I tried to import the [Gears API for Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=gwt-google-apis&s=gwt-google-apis&t=GearsGettingStarted).  After adding the following line to my java source file:

```
import com.google.gwt.gears.client.geolocation.Geolocation;
```

I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
19-Jun-2009 3:36:09 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@1c7d682{/,C:\Documents and Settings\Geoff Denning\workspace\TaskPath\war}
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
```

I've already added the gwt-gears.jar file to my \war\WEB-INF\lib directory, and I've referenced it in Eclipse as follows:

[image: Java Build Path in Eclipse]

I've even opened the gwt-gears.jar file and confirmed that org/apache/xerces/jaxp/SAXParserFactoryImpl.class does exist.  Can anyone give me any pointers as to why I'm getting the above error?

Comment: what version of java are you using? Have you recently changed the version from 1.4 to 1.5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in jre 1.5.  I was able to resolve the problem by switching my default JRE in Eclipse from 1.5.0_06 to 1.6.0_03, as shown below:

[image: Eclipse Installed JREs]

Thanks to [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82865/jon) and [Rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24424/rahul) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Check that Xerces exists in:

```
$JAVA_HOME/lib/endorsed
```

Sounds like a Java 5 issue.  Also check the Java system property for:

```
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
```

It should be:

```
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
```

If not then that's your issue, make sure you set the system property.

Comment: In practice, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. I had conflicting JARs in my workspace. I removed one and boom it worked. The message didn't lend very well to the root of the error.

Comment: In my case, after days fighting with the exact same problem, I found I had a `SAXParserFactoryImpl` class in a `xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar` in one of my uses library. 

I just had to copy this jar into the WEB-INF/lib and add it to the .settings\com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.prefs

Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

My **SAXParserFactoryImpl problem** was caused by gwt-gadgets.jar I had in my boot class path. Removing this JAR from the boot class path solved the problem for me. Basically you have to **remove any JAR containing a SAXParserFactoryImpl class from your build path (user libs)**.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/jaxp.properties fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Trouble with Selenium (XercesImpl) and Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165358/trouble-with-selenium-xercesimpl-and-google-app-engine).
I had a similar problem with GWT / GAE (SAXParserFactoyImpl not found) and solved it by;

1. Importing the jar to war/WEB-INF/lib
2. Adding the jar to the build path