# Gears complaints about JRE 1.5 in GWT project

Tags: gwt, java, google-gears

I just tried to use Gears in my GWT application and got following error:

```
Jul 12, 2009 6:26:29 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Jul 12, 2009 6:26:29 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@c45809{/,/Users/work/workspace/Athena/war}
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.<init>(XmlParser.java:69)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.webXmlParser(WebXmlConfiguration.java:83)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.<init>(WebXmlConfiguration.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:494)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:350)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.loadConfigurations(WebAppContext.java:838)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:417)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:217)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:147)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:116)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:86)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode.doStartUpServer(HostedMode.java:365)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.HostedModeBase.startUp(HostedModeBase.java:590)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.HostedModeBase.run(HostedModeBase.java:397)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode.main(HostedMode.java:232)
```

I know this error is because I'm using (1) OS X, (2) Eclipse with Google Plugin, (3) **JRE 1.5**. But I have no choice because Hosted Mode plugin requires JRE 1.5 and when I switch to JRE 1.6 Hosted mode complains. I also tried to set JRE 1.6 just to the project, still Plugin does not like it.
This problem occurs only when I'm including

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.gears.Gears'/>
```

into my gwt.xml file.

There is [one guy who has same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016286/org-apache-xerces-jaxp-saxparserfactoryimpl-not-found-when-importing-gears-api-in), he solved it by just switching JRE's but I'm using Mac and I assume there is different story with Mac. Is there any solutions to this problem in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of gwt-gears.jar are you using?  Make sure you are 
running the latest gwt-gears release (1.2.1) and try 
gwt-gears-noredist.jar if you are using the Google Plugin.