# Xerces JAR on GAE project's classpath leads to "SAXParserFactoryImpl not found"

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jetty

I'm using the Eclipse plugin for Google App Engine and I'm having a strange issue with a Xerces dependency. 
On of my classes depends on the Apache Xerces JAR which I have added to the project's classpath. This however, triggers an error when starting the Jetty app server:

```
WARNING: failed 
com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@6efde050 
{/,/Users/lenni/dev/gate/war} 
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider 
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
```

When I remove the xercesImpl.jar from my classpath jetty starts fine, however then my classes don't compile anymore since the dependency is missing.

This very much sound like this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016286/org-apache-xerces-jaxp-saxparserfactoryimpl-not-found-when-importing-gears-api-in), however I tried switching to JRE 1.6 and still no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to relate to [Issue 1367](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1367) in the GAE/J buglist.  Comments 15, 16, and 17 seem to indicate a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I the problem is not with the *lack* of the Xerces lib but with its presence on the classpath!

Comment: The comments on the bug mentioned a similar problem to yours if some of the xerces APIs were missing (ie, xercesImpl.jar, but not some of the other jars).  It isn't clear from your question if you are copying them all.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Trouble with Selenium (XercesImpl) and Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165358/trouble-with-selenium-xercesimpl-and-google-app-engine). I had a similar problem with GAE (SAXParserFactoyImpl not found) and solved it by;

1. Importing the jar to war/WEB-INF/lib
2. Adding the jar to the build path