# Trouble with Selenium (XercesImpl) and Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, selenium, saxparser

I downloaded selenium-java-2.0b3.zip from the [Selenium Downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list). I unzipped it and added all the .jars to the build path of a simple Eclipse project:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
    }
}
```

This works fine. I then try to do add all the libraries to the build path of a GWT/GAE project. Without adding any code that references the libraries, I see these errors when I try to run the project:

```
Initializing AppEngine server
Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Successfully processed foo\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Successfully processed foo\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
[WARN] failed com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@495e160e{/,foo\war}: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
[WARN] failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@3ffa16c3: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
[WARN] Error starting handlers
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.setValidating(XmlParser.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.<init>(XmlParser.java:83)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration.configureWebApp(TagLibConfiguration.java:210)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:186)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:169)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:500)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1055)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:804)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:309)
[WARN] Nested in javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findJarServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.setValidating(XmlParser.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.<init>(XmlParser.java:83)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration.configureWebApp(TagLibConfiguration.java:210)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:186)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:169)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:500)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1055)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:804)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:309)
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016286/org-apache-xerces-jaxp-saxparserfactoryimpl-not-found-when-importing-gears-api-in) may have some insight.

**Update 2**: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200637/xerces-jar-on-gae-projects-classpath-leads-to-saxparserfactoryimpl-not-found).

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the jars in the Selenium download to `war/WEB-INF/lib` and add them to the build path.