# Create xml document in java applet

Tags: java, xml, applet

If I try to create a new xml document in a java applet by this code:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance()

```
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
```

I will get this error:

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_19
Using JRE version 1.6.0_19-b04 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> not found
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I do not care about DTD's.

1. Why is it looking for it?
2. How am I supposed to **create a xml document in java applets**?
3. How can I make it work?

The enclosing html document looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Loading...</title>
</head>
```

[Can some comment this thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5428124)?

> The problem was with the entity resolver, which points to 
>   the w3c.org web site. The access to the reference DTDs on 
>   this site has been restricted for application use. The 
>   solution was to implement my own entity resolver.

Related:

1. http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=515055
2. [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found when importing Gears API in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016286/org-apache-xerces-jaxp-saxparserfactoryimpl-not-found-when-importing-gears-api-in)
3. http://java.itags.org/java-desktop/4839/

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is calling `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();` then this should not cause an error. The posts you link to are not relevant.

`javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> not found`

This suggests some weird configuration error/bug. The provider should (I think) be the factory class name of the JAXP implementation. Check that you aren't doing something strange like setting the `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` system property or have an invalid `META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` file on your Applet classpath.

Answer (score 0):

```
    JAVA FX SERVER
    
    THREAD   
    
    public class ServerThread extends Thread {
        // Server related fields.
        private ObjectOutputStream oos;
        private ObjectInputStream ois;
        private ServerSocket server;
        private Socket connection;
        private int counter = 1;
        private Displayer<String> displayer;
        private Runnable onConnected;
        private Runnable onDisconnected;
    
        public ServerThread(Displayer<String> displayer, Runnable onConnected, Runnable onDisconnected) {
            this.displayer = displayer;
            this.onConnected = onConnected;
            this.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
        }
    
        protected void display(String message) {
            if(displayer == null) return;
    
            displayer.display(message);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Step 1: Create a ServerSocket.
                server = new ServerSocket(5001, 100);
                display("Started server: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
    
                while (true) {
                    // Step 2: Wait for a connection.
                    waitForConnection();
    
                    // Step 3: Get input and output streams.
                    getStreams();
    
                    // Step 4: Process connection.
                    readMessages();
    
                    // Step 5: Close connection.
                    closeConnection();
    
                    ++counter;
                }
            } catch (
                    EOFException eofException) {
                display("Client terminated connection");
    
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        // Send message to client
        public void sendMessage(String message) {
            try {
                message = "SERVER>>> " + message;
    
                // Send String OBJECT to client.
                oos.writeObject(message);
                // Flush to ensure that data is pushed through stream to client.
                oos.flush();
    
                display(message);
    
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                display("Error writing object. " + ioException.getMessage());
            }
        }
    
        // Wait for connection to arrive, then display connection info
        private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
            display("Waiting for connection...");
    
            connection = server.accept();
    
            display("Connection #" + counter + " received from: "
                    + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        }
    
        // Get streams to send and receive data
        private void getStreams() throws IOException {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            oos.flush();
    
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    
            display("Got I/O streams.");
        }
    
        // Process connection with client
        private void readMessages() throws IOException {
            // Send initial message to client.
            String message = "Connection successful. Client #" + counter;
            sendMessage(message);
    
            // Connected
            if(onConnected != null) onConnected.run();
    
            do {
                try {
                    message = (String) ois.readObject();
                    display(message);
    
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
                    display("Unknown object type received.");
                }
    
            } while (!message.equals("CLIENT>>> TERMINATE"));
        }
    
        // close streams and socket
        private void closeConnection() throws IOException {
            display("User terminated connection.");
            oos.close();
            ois.close();
            connection.close();
    
            if(onDisconnected != null) onDisconnected.run();
        }
    }
    MAIN JAVAFX
    
    public class Server2JFX extends Application {
        // Cached references to controls.
        private TextField txtMessage;
        private ObservableList<String> messages
                = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ArrayList<String>());
    
        // Thread on which server runs.
        private ServerThread serverThread;
    
        private Scene createScene() {
            // Main container.
            BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    
            // The area where the user will enter messages to be
            // sent from the server to the client.
            txtMessage = new TextField();
            // Event handler used to send message to client.
            txtMessage.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
                // If not the enter key, do nothing.
                if(event.getCode() != KeyCode.ENTER) return;
    
                // Send message to client.
                String message = txtMessage.getText();
                new Thread(() -> serverThread.sendMessage(message)).start();
    
                // Clear text field.
                txtMessage.setText("");
            });
    
            // Area to store messages received.
            ListView<String> lbxMessages = new ListView<>();
            lbxMessages.setItems(messages);
    
            // Add controls to container.
            bp.setTop(txtMessage);
            bp.setCenter(lbxMessages);
    
            // Return a new scene graph.
            return new Scene(bp);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            // Create scene.
            Scene scene = createScene();
    
            // Set stage details.
            primaryStage.setTitle("Server 2 (JavaFX front-end)");
            primaryStage.setWidth(300);
            primaryStage.setMinHeight(500);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    
            // Show stage.
            primaryStage.show();
    
            // Create the server thread.
            serverThread = new ServerThread(
                    message -> Platform.runLater(() -> messages.add(message)), // How to display message.
                    () -> Platform.runLater(() -> txtMessage.setEditable(true)), // What to do when connected (run on UI thread).
                    () -> Platform.runLater(() -> txtMessage.setEditable(false)) // What to do when connected (run on UI thread).
            );
            // Start running the server.
            serverThread.start();
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }

package nmu.wrpv302.l08;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Displayer<T> {
    void display(T value);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).