# using spring aop pointcut getting error although i had added aspectjrt.jar also

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

Not able to solve this problem
Error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError:
>   Provider
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
>   not found
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:932)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1933)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1605)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
>           at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont think the error is due to the missing aspect related jars. the root cause seems to be "Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl". your classpath doesnt include an implementation for the sax parser factory. This thread is helpful: [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found when importing Gears API in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016286/org-apache-xerces-jaxp-saxparserfactoryimpl-not-found-when-importing-gears-api-in)